# Error when opening a csv file in a function

Tags: python, csv

Basic question, but I get an error when I run this Python program, and the error is coming on the line `f = open("eurusdfunctions.csv","r")`
Error is:

```
File "C:/Users/lukas/PycharmProjects/stockprediction/feature_functions.py", line 5, in some_function
    f = open("eurusdfunctions.csv","r")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any help would be much appreaciated.

```
import csv
import sys

def some_function(position):
    f = open("eurusdfunctions.csv","r")
    f.seek(position)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        break
    f.close()

file = open("eurusd.csv","r")
position = 0
reader1 = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader1:
    time,open,high,low,close,volume=line
    position = position + sys.getsizeof(time) + sys.getsizeof(open) + sys.getsizeof(high) + sys.getsizeof(low) + sys.getsizeof(close) + sys.getsizeof(volume)
    neka_funkcija(position)
    file.close()
```

Comment: You shadow the `open()` function and overwrite it with a string here `time,open,high,low,close,volume=line`

Comment: Thanks so much... I totally overlooked that.